# Determinant using Row and Column operations/expansions

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

We are asked to show that:

$$
    \det\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    2 & 3 & 7 & 1 & 3\\
    2 & 3 & 7 & 1 & 5\\
    2 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 9\\
    4 & 6 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    5 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 5
    \end{array}\right] = 2
$$

By using suitable elementary row and column operations as well as row and column expansions. I have used:

$$ R_2 - R_1 \to R_2 $$
$$ R_3 - R_1 \to R_3 $$
$$ 2R_1 - R_4 \to R_4 $$

Which is the following matrix:

$$
    \det\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    2 & 3 & 7 & 1 & 3\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 6\\
    0 & 0 & 12 & -1 & 2\\
    5 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 5
    \end{array}\right] = 2
$$

I would surmise now using either a row or column expansion, but need clarification/confirmation.

Comment: Note that when using the ERO $2R_{1}-R_{4}\rightarrow R_{4}$, you will need to factor out $-1$. It is best to use the ERO $-2R_{1}+R_{4}\rightarrow R_{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand by row 2, then by (original) row 3, then by row 4, leaving a single $2\times 2$ determinant that you can do manually.